# C++ problems with division

Tags: c++, division, integer-division, divide-by-zero, floor-division

I need to make a program in C++ in which I insert a number 'n' that's with 4 digits and it's a simple number, in the console and the console is showing me the multiplication of the certain number with 4 digits which I first needed to write.
I tried to write (n/!2) in order to make the program execute only if the number can't divide by 2 and the console showed `"main.cpp:22:36: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]".`
I've tried removing
(n /! 2) and the code got executed without a problem. I will be glad if someone can tell me how can I fix it.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int getProduct(int n)
{
    int product = 1;
    while (n != 0) {
        product = product * (n % 10);
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return product;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "insert n ";
    cin >> n;
    if (n >= 1000 && n <= 9999 && n /! 2) {
        cout << (getProduct(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't compile this. Please read [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: What this `(n /! 2)` suppose to mean?

Comment: @Slava (n /! 2) is the same as !+ or !- but with division, I hope. I tried adding the ! before / but it got me another error: expected ‘)’ before ‘!’ token

Comment: @ТодорСлавов `!+` and `!-` is not a special thing. Using `!` on an integer will treat the integer as a `bool` where anything but `0` is `true` (1) and `0` is `false` (0). The `!` reverses that so that `true` becomes `false` and vice versa. When a `bool` is used in arithmetic context (like in your division), it's promoted to an `int` (0 or 1). In this case `0`.

Comment: "(n /! 2) is the same as !+ or !- but with division" I am afraid you do not understand what `!+` or `!-` does. You need to learn basics of the language instead of inventing your own understanding on how operations work in C++

Answer (score 2):

In the calculation `n / !2` You effectively do `n / 0`.

`!` is short for `not`, `not 2` is a boolean expression where `2` (anything but `0`) is `true`.

`not true` is `false`.

`false` is promoted to an `int` in the calculation and `false` there becomes `0`.

Solution: Use `n % 2 != 0` or `n & 1` to check for odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for modulo operation. Modulo (the remainder from division) is equal to zero if number is divisible by the other one and non-zero otherwise.

```
if (n >=1000 && n <= 9999 && (n % 2) != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

> tried to write (n/!2) in order to make the program execute only if the number can't divide by 2

```
n / !2
```

This evaluates to `n / 0`. which triggers your warning.

To check if `n` is odd, you should do this instead:

```
n % 2 != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

! operator have higher precedence than / , So your expression becomes

=>  n/(!2)
=>  n/0

Instead you shoud use (n%2==0) to check for even number.